# ld returned 1 exit status - Windows 8 x64

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, windows-8.1

So i'm putting together a program to print the binary representation of different data types and when I got to compile I get these errors

---

> C:\Users\Bryant\AppData\Local\Temp\cckEPS7f.o binaryrepresentation.cpp:(.text+0x133): undefined reference to `printChar(char, std::ostream&)'
>
> C:\Users\Bryant\AppData\Local\Temp\cckEPS7f.o binaryrepresentation.cpp:(.text+0x16e): undefined reference to `printShort(int, std::ostream&)'
>
> C:\Users\Bryant\AppData\Local\Temp\cckEPS7f.o binaryrepresentation.cpp:(.text+0x1a7): undefined reference to `printFloat(int, std::ostream&)'
>
> c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe  C:\Users\Bryant\AppData\Local\Temp\cckEPS7f.o: bad reloc address 0xc in section `.xdata'
>
> C:\Users\Bryant\SkyDrive\Documents\Data Structures 2014\collect2.exe  [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

---

here is my driver

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "display.h"

union FloatValue
{
int intView;
float floatView;
};

main()
{
cout    << "----------------------------Menu-------------------------" << endl
        << " 1 - Print the binary representation of a character" << endl
        << " 2 - Print the binary representation of a short integer" << endl
        << " 3 - Print the binary representation of a float" << endl
        << " 4 - Exit Program";
        
cout << "Enter your selection: ";
int selection = 0;
cin >> selection;
        
while (selection != 4)
{
    char charInput = '0';
    short int intInput = 0;
    switch(selection)
    {
        case 1: cout << "\nEnter a character: ";
                cin >> charInput;
                printChar(charInput, cout);
                break;
        case 2: cout << "\nEnter a short: ";
                cin >> intInput;
                printShort(intInput, cout);
                break;
        case 3: cout << "\nEnter a short: ";
                FloatValue num;
                cin >> num.floatView;
                printFloat(num.intView, cout);
                break;
        case 4: break;
    }
    cout << "\nEnter your selection: ";
    cout    << "----------------------------Menu-------------------------" << endl
        << " 1 - Print the binary representation of a character" << endl
        << " 2 - Print the binary representation of a short integer" << endl
        << " 3 - Print the binary representation of a float" << endl
        << " 4 - Exit Program";
    cin >> selection;
}
```

}

---

and here is my header "display.h"

```
//          display.h

/*
    Basic operations:
    Print a char
    Print a short int
    Print a float
*/
#include <iostream>

void printChar(char val, ostream & out);
/* -----------------------------------
    Prints the binary representation of a user inputed character

    Receives: A char value from user
*/

void printShort(int val, ostream & out);
/* ------------------------------------
    Prints the binary representation of a user inputed integer

    Receives: An integer value from user
*/

void printFloat(int val, ostream & out);
/* ------------------------------------
    Prints the binary representation of a user inputed float

    Receives: A float-converted-to-int value from user
*/
```

---

When I try to compile me header I get the same errors listed above but when I compile my implementation file I get a different error.

[Error] iostream: No such file or directory

here is my implementation file "display.cpp"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "display.h"


// --- Utility Functions

union FloatVal;

// --- Definition of Utility Function-----------------------------------------

union FloatVal
{
    int intView;
    float floatView;
};


// --- Definition of printChar ----------------------------------------------

void printChar(char val, ostream & out)
{

    int dataSize = sizeof(char)* 8;
    unsigned char mask = 2 ^ (dataSize - 1);

    for(int dataSize; dataSize > 0; dataSize--)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        if(counter == 4)
        {
            out << " ";
            counter = 0;
        };
        if((val & mask) != 0)
        {
            out << "1";
        }

        else
        {
            out << "0";
        };

        mask >> 1;
        counter++;
    }
}

// --- Definition of printShort----------------------------------------------

void printShort(int val, ostream & out)
{
    int dataSize = sizeof(short int)* 8;
    unsigned int mask = 2 ^ (dataSize - 1);

    for(int dataSize; dataSize > 0; dataSize--)
    {
        int counter = 0;

        if(counter == 4)
        {
            out << " ";
            counter = 0;

        }

        if((val & mask) != 0)
        {
            out << "1";
        }

        else
        {
            out << "0";
        };

        mask >> 1;
        counter++;

    }
}

// --- Definition of printFloat-----------------------------------------------

void printFloat(int val, ostream & out)
{

    int dataSize = sizeof(float)* 8;
    unsigned int mask = 2 ^ (dataSize - 1);

    for(int dataSize; dataSize > 0; dataSize--)
    {
        int counter = 0;

        if(counter == 4)
        {
            out << " ";
        }

        if((val & mask) != 0)
        {
            out << "1";
        }

        else
        {
            out << "0";
        };

        mask >> 1;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

I tried searching for a solution to the error but almost all of the posts were about linux users, and the ones that were never answered the question.

Comment: Please show the commands you use to build the program. It simply seems you don't link with the object file containing the sought-after functions.

Comment: Im using Orwell Dev C++, I was assuming this did it for me. Otherwise Im not sure if they are linked or not.